# Modifying JSXGraph grid default parameters

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

What is the correct way to set the grid parameters for JSXGraph? [According to here](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Options),

> ... [default] values have to be overwritten before the initialization of the JSXGraph board.

[So, currently I'm trying](http://jsfiddle.net/3hjwchtp/1/) the following:

```
JXG.Options.grid.strokeColor = "pink";
JXG.Options.grid.strokeWidth = 14.0;
board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-5,5,5,-5], axis: true});
```

which doesn't affect anything.

However, I *can* create a grid on existing board, but this draws underneath the existing grid for some reason. The board seems to ignore if initialize with `grid: false` as well, so I can't seem to work around it. Any ideas?

---

#### small update

I found that

```
JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-5,5,5,-5], axis: true, grid: true})
```

draws an additional grid on top of the grid drawn by the `axis: true` argument. However, the colors for the first grid drawn by the `axis:true` argument are coupled to the

```
JXG.Options.axis.ticks.strokeColor
```

parameter. For odd some reason, this parameter changes both the tick color and and the grid drawn by the axis (which is drawn even in the case of `axis: true` and `grid: false`). [Here is an example of what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/d8xz1915/).

Answer (score 1):

In JSXGraph there are two type of grid lines:

- A grid object which can be displayed with `grid:true` and whose attributes can be set with `JXG.Options.grid`. The distance between two grid lines is set with `JXG.Options.grid.gridX` and `JXG.Options.grid.gridY`.
- The ticks of an axis can stretch infinitely. This is the case for the major ticks of the default axis. One can set the pixel length of the minor and mayor ticks of an axis with

  `JXG.Options.axis.ticks.majorHeight = 20;
  JXG.Options.axis.ticks.minorHeight = 10;`

  If these attributes have negative values the tick will stretch infinitely and thus will appear as grid line. The default value of `JXG.Options.axis.ticks.majorHeight` is `-1`. Minor ticks and major ticks will have the same color.

The lines of the (true) grid will always have the same distance in user coordinates, independent from the zoom level, while the infinite ticks lines will adapt to the zoom level.
If the user choose a high zoom level, the browser may freeze because of the many grid lines.

Comment: This is interesting, but I'm confused. I simply want to set the default of the background grid lines without changing the tick colors or spacing, and without drawing multiples grids. How can I do this?

Comment: So, go for alternative 2: `JXG.Options.axis.ticks.strokeColor = "somecolor"`

Comment: I appreciate your time, but I don't see how this is a second alternative because your initial answer doesn't address my question, unless I'm misunderstanding you. If you read my question above, you'll see I've already tried what you mention now, but that this has the side-effect of changing the tick colors in addition to the grid line colors. I'm simply asking if it's possible to **only change the grid color without getting rid of the axis**.